# Why does instanceof fail for a derived class in TypeScript?

Tags: inheritance, typescript, instanceof

I have a strange problem where instanceof doesn't seem to work properly for a derived class in TypeScript. The structure of my classes is as follows:

```
interface Serializing 
{
    serialize(): string 
}

class Storage implements Serializing
{
    // constructor, methods, serialize, ...
}

class StorageContainer
{
    // constructor, methods, various methods that act on storage_, ...

    protected storage_: Storage;
}

class Derived extends StorageContainer
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        let test1 = this instanceof Derived; // succeeds
        let test2 = this instanceof StorageContainer; // succeeds
    }

    // ... constructor, methods, ...
}
```

and I then run this method using these classes:

```
testInstanceofOnDerivedClasses()
{
    let derived = new Derived();

    let test1 = derived instanceof Derived; // succeeds
    let test2 = derived instanceof StorageContainer; // fails?
}
```

I was of course expecting test2 to be true (as the class Derived is clearly derived from the class StorageContainer), but for some reason it returns false...

I also did tests with other simpler derived classes, and there instanceof does work as expected. Only in this particular case I have, it doesn't.

Also remarkable: when I do the 2 tests inside the constructor of Derived, they both succeed...

So, my questions are:

- What could be things to watch for that can lead to the instanceof
  functionality to break?
- What could be a possible reason that the tests succeed inside the 
  constructor, but not outside?
- Do you have any advice as to how to debug this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tested your code in playground, and other than getting `"Duplicate identifier 'Storage'"` it was ok, the 2nd test `derived instanceof StorageContainer` returns true

Comment: This is not my exact code: as mentioned, this is just showing the structure of my classes. It's impossible to post all my code, as the real case is much more involved.

I also created small test examples, with a similar structure, but there things work as expected.

That's why I was asking what kinds of things could be causing instanceof to fail, given a structure as outlined above.

Comment: There's no way of knowing, the problem you are facing may be a result of A LOT of things.  If you can't reproduce the issue with a simple example, then you better check the prototype chain of the instance that returns false for `instanceof`.

Comment: OK, thanks. Would this be the idea then: create an object for which instanceof succeeds, then compare the prototype fields at all levels with these of an object that fails, and look for missing/extra fields?
Actually what I really can't understand is why the tests succeed while still in the constructor right before returning, but once outside of it, they fail...
I guess I could start with checking what changes to the object when returning from the constructor.

Comment: My guess is that the variable which you think that contains an instance of `X` actually doesn't have it. Maybe it has nothing, maybe an instance of a different type.